# Excessive number of pages when printing a webpage

Tags: printing, drupal, printing-web-page

So I am trying to print a webpage with `javascript:window.print();`. Rest of the website works perfectly fine. There is this one page where the data is coming from 3rd party sources which might be the culprit but I am not sure at this moment. But when I try to print this page the print window shows 'Loading preview...' and total number of pages are astonishing 31000+. When it should hardly be a 3 page print.

[image]

When I turn OFF my VPN (which allow me to access those 3rd party sources and fetch and render the data on the page) the access is revoked from the 3rd party sources, making the print work fine with only 1 page.

[image]

I tried searching on the internet for this issue but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The application is built in Drupal 9 having twig as template engine. So I simply fixed html indentation and found out it was an extra `</div>` tag which was causing this issue. So guys always indent your code and be careful with writing lots of html in a single template. :)